# Can I get the output of a command into the current command line in bash so I can edit it?

Tags: bash, terminal, gnome-terminal

I know I can use `$()` or assign the output of a command to a variable and then use that.  But can I paste the output of a command onto the current command-line so that I can edit it?

If I have a mouse, it's easy - copy and paste.  But sometimes I work on systems where using a mouse is quite inconvenient.  Is there a way to do this form a keyboard only?

Typical use case is when I want to tag a git repository:

```
$ git describe
2.20.0-5-1-g99a731f4e3
```

I then want to `git tag 2.20.0-6`.  Is there a way to get the previous tag onto the command line so I can edit it?  Other than typing it, obviously.  Or constructing a `sed` command to make the edit.

Answer (score 6):

Figured out shortly after asking this question that `xsel` can do most of what I want.  Specifically:

```
git describe | xsel -i -b
```

will put the output of `git describe` into the clipboard (or primary or secondary selection if you use `-p` or `-s` instead of `-b`).  Then you can paste the result using Ctrl+Shift+V in GNOME terminal or other equivalents in other terminal emulators.

Comment: I was about to post this. I want to add that use can use `!!` as a shortcut fr the previous command, so it reduces to `!! | xsel -i -b`.